# Loading a layer into the same position as an existing layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python

I understand that it is not possible to directly reload a shapefile layer in QGIS using the `reload` method in Python, since this method is not implemented for shapefile data providers. Thus, the workaround is to unload the layer and then reload the layer.

However, if one does this naively, the new layer will show up at the top of the map legend, rather than at the position that the original layer occupied. Is there a straightforward way to save the position of the old layer and then reload a new layer at that same position?

Comment: Have you tried just refreshing? Or simply a close and re-open. Not sure what the use case is?

Comment: My use case is that I am allowing a user to automatically generate and modify shapefiles via Python code in the QGIS console, and I want to automatically reload layers when they are changed in order to show the changes. I would prefer not to make the changes directly via the QGIS API because my code also runs outside of QGIS and I don't really want to have two ways of writing the output.

Comment: in arcmap I just hit refresh (F5) or even a slight zoom and get my latest shapefile changes. perhaps the console has a "redraw map" or refresh?

Comment: The refresh function in PyQGIS does not work with shapefile layers.

Comment: Is there anything (manually) that happens in qgis that does show the new changes?

Comment: From what I have read, the recommended way is to unload the layer and then reload it. Thus my question of how one can reload the layer into the same position on the legend.

Comment: not sure how you can use it but I was able to refresh my shape file after modifying it (externally) using the render toggle. I looked it up but cant see a control for just on/off. but that is what I did. just turned it off and back on and my shape file updated.